# How to stop function after 1 second Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code, I am calling a Slow motion function when the player enter to a Trigger, but I want this function to stop after 1 second, I tried the code below but the slow motion didn't work. Do you have any idea?

**Player Script:**

```
public Rigidbody Ball;
public float Speed = 50f;
public TimeManager timeManager;
bool SlowOn;
bool ClickDone = false;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(SlowOff());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (!ClickDone){
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            ClickDone = true;
            Ball.velocity = transform.forward * Speed;
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag ("SlowMotionArea")) {
        if (SlowOn) {
            timeManager.DoSlowMotion();
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator SlowOff () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    SlowOn = false;
}
```

**TimeManager Script:**

```
    public float SlowDownFactor = 0.05f;
    public float SlowdownLength = 2f;

    public void DoSlowMotion () {    
        Time.timeScale = SlowDownFactor;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale ;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the condition for doing slow motion if the player Z is equal to 0 I also don't see you trying to do it for 1 second.  Not to mention no idea what TimeManager is or is doing...

Comment: @Eddge Can you check my question again please? I've updated it

Comment: Where do you set the `SlowOn` to `true`?

Comment: @ming060 In the collision

Comment: So, the problem is that slow motion doesn't work or cannot stop the slow motion after one second?

Comment: @ming060 the slow motion doesn't work

Comment: I don't see where you set `SlowOn` to `true` neither and claim that `timeManager.DoSlowMotion();` is simply never called. You should change the subject if your problem isn't even stopping but starting the slow motion.

Comment: @derHugo I turned the SlowOn to true in the OnTriggerEnter

Comment: `I turned the SlowOn to true in the OnTriggerEnter` .. No, not in the script you provided here. Is there another one?

Comment: @derHugo The script provided here has been edited by someone, but in the original script there is:     private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("SlowMotionArea")){
            if (SlowOn == true)
            {
                timeManager.DoSlowMotion();
                SpeedEffect.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: `== true` only compares but doesn't **set** `SlowOn` to `true`. `if(SlowOn)` is the same as `if(SlowOn == true)`. To set it you would have to call `SlowOn = true;` somwhere in your script

Comment: @derHugo yes it works now, but the slow Motion didn't stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code

1. You never set `SlowOn` to `true` so your line

   ```
   timeManager.DoSlowMotion();
   ```

   is never executed. Somewhere in your code you should call

   ```
   SlowOn = true;
   ```

   I'm guessing but it seems that you wanted to use that bool to prevent multiple calls of `timeManager.DoSlowMotion()`? In this case it should rather be something like

   ```
   if(!SlowOn)
   {
       timeManager.DoSlowMotion();
       SlowOn = true;
   }
   ```
2. Why do you call `StartCoroutine(SlowOff());` in your `Start()` method?

   I guess you should rather remove that line and place it after

   ```
   timeManager.DoSlowMotion();
   StartCoroutine(SlowOff());
   ```

   so the Coroutine is started everytime a SlowMotion starts.
3. It is not enough for the SlowMotion to stop to just set your `SlowOn = false`.

   In your `TimeManager` you should rather store the original TimeScale and reset them in a second method:

   ```
   public float SlowDownFactor = 0.05f;
   public float SlowdownLength = 2f;

   private float originalTimeScale;
   private float originalFixedDeltaTime;

   public void DoSlowMotion () {   

       // before changing store current values
       originalTimeScale = Time.timeScale;
       originalFixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime;

       Time.timeScale = SlowDownFactor;
       Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale ;
   }

   public void ResetTimeScales()
   {
       Time.timeScale = originalTimeScale;
       Time.fixedDeltaTime = originalFixedDeltaTime;
   }
   ```

   and than you also have to call that `ResetTimeScales` method from the player

   ```
   IEnumerator SlowOff () {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
       timeManager.ResetTimeScales();
       SlowOn = false;
   }
   ```
4. I guess you know that

   ```
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
   ```

   will also be affected by the changed Timescale so your SlowMotion currently would be longer than the expected `2` seconds namely `2 / SlowDownFactor` =  `40`!

   You could avoid this by using the `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` as a countdown like

   ```
   private IEnumerator SlowOff()
   {
       // since your title actually claims you want to reset after 1 second
       float timer = 1;

       while (timer > 0)
       {
           timer -= Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
           yield return null;
       }

       timeManager.ResetTimeScales();
       SlowDown = false;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks but the SlowMotion still didn't stop :(

Comment: How long did you wait? Note that `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);` is also affected by the changed timescale see point 4

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, but I solved the problem by adding this code to TimeManager script:     private void Update(){
        Time.timeScale += (1f / SlowdownLength) * Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
        Time.timeScale = Mathf.Clamp(Time.timeScale, 0f, 1f);
    }

Comment: well this is "fading" the slowmotion back to normal time and not in the scope of this question. I also just wanted to suggest the unscaledDeltaTime see point 4

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate your help, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! Note that I just updated my answer again -> ofcourse you can keep your Coroutine as well and use the unscaledDeltaTime in it. Depends a bit on your design and who should be responsible for what